# Error in using by on a dataframe/table in R

Tags: r

Firstly apologies as I am unable to produce a fully reproducible example, but please bear with me.

I have a data table/ data frame (according to 'class') which looks like this (called variable.nuts1_MALE.counts):

```
   country region   N freq.1 result level delete_to.few.observations
1:      DE    DE2 187     15   8.41     1                          1
2:      DE    DE1 142      9   7.30     1                          1
3:      DE    DEA 231     19   8.75     1                          1
4:      DE    DED 136      5   5.32     1                          1
5:      DE    DE9 114     13  11.40     1                          1
6:      UK    UKJ 147     14   6.35     1                          1
7:      UK    UKD 108     12   7.36     1                          1
```

And then I wish to run the following lines of code that add an extra column according to how many regions there are in each country (adding 1 for 5 or more (i.e. DE) and 0 for less than 5 (i.e. UK)):

```
setDT(variable.nuts1_MALE.counts)[, delete_too.few.regions:= if(.N < 5) "0" else "1", by = unlist(country)]
variable.nuts1_MALE.regions <- subset(variable.nuts1_MALE.counts, delete_too.few.regions == 1)
```

This has always been working on all the other data I have been running, however this time I get the error message:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(variable.nuts1_MALE.counts), , `:=`(delete_too.few.regions,  : 

  'by' appears to evaluate to column names but isn't c() or key(). Use by=list(...) if you can. Otherwise, by=eval(unlist(country)) should work. This is for efficiency so data.table can detect which columns are needed.
```

Can anyone please advise what's going wrong?

When I try the suggestions (probably badly), I get error messages:

```
setDT(variable.nuts1_MALE.counts)[, delete_too.few.regions:= if(.N < 5) "0" else "1", by=eval(unlist(country))]
Error in unlist(country) : object 'country' not found

setDT(variable.nuts1_MALE.counts)[, delete_too.few.regions:= if(.N < 5) "0" else "1", by = list(country)]

Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(variable.nuts1_MALE.counts), , `:=`(delete_too.few.regions,  : 
  column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type list. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]
```

I can't seem to reproduce the error when I dput the table, but here is the data if anyone has any alternative suggestions.

```
variable.nuts1_MALE.counts <- structure(list(country = list("DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "UK", 
                              "UK"), region = c("DE2", "DE1", "DEA", "DED", "DE9", "UKJ", 
                                                "UKD"), N = c(187L, 142L, 231L, 136L, 114L, 147L, 108L), freq.1 = c(15L, 
                                                                                                                    9L, 19L, 5L, 13L, 14L, 12L), result = c(8.41, 7.3, 8.75, 5.32, 
                                                                                                                                                            11.4, 6.35, 7.36), level = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), delete_to.few.observations = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("country", "region", "N", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "freq.1", "result", "level", "delete_to.few.observations"), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Is `country` a list column?

Comment: Thanks @Roland - how would I check that?

Comment: According to your `dput` output it is a list column. Maybe you should just do `setDT(variable.nuts1_MALE.counts); variable.nuts1_MALE.counts[, country := unlist(country)]; variable.nuts1_MALE.counts[, delete_too.few.regions:= .N >= 5, by = country]`